# Why does Type.IsByRef for type String return false if String is a reference type?

Tags: c#, .net

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/362314fe.aspx) a string (or String) is a reference type.

Yet given:

```
Type t = typeof(string);
```

then

```
if (t.IsByRef) ...
```

returns false

why?

Edit: After some quick testing, I'm obviously misunderstanding the purpose of IsByRef...
as even using a class name in place of 'string' ,returns false as well. I'm writing a generic class and want to test if one the types passed in when the generic is instantiate is a value or reference type. How does one test for this?

Comment: The word **`By`** there isn't just for decoration, it has a meaning. ;)

Comment: @Mehrdad - well said - now that I know the purpose .IsByRef!

Comment: The IsByRef is only used by a function's argument's definition to determine if it is configured as ref/out (ByRef in VB.net). The class types will never have IsByRef set to true.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use `IsValueType` instead:

```
bool f = !typeof (string).IsValueType; //return true;
```

As for `IsByRef`, the purpose of this property is to determine whether the parameter is passed into method by ref or by value.

Example you have a method which `a` is passed by ref:

```
public static void Foo(ref int a)
{
}
```

You can determine whether `a` is pass by reference or not:

```
  bool f = typeof (Program).GetMethod("Foo")
                                 .GetParameters()
                                 .First()
                                 .ParameterType
                                 .IsByRef;   //return true
```

Answer (score 12):

There are "reference types" -- for which we have `!type.IsValueType` -- and then there are types that *represent references* to *anything* -- whether their targets are value types or reference types.

When you say `void Foo(ref int x)`, the `x` is said to be "passed **by reference**", hence `ByRef`.
Under the hood, `x` ***is*** a *reference* of the type `ref int`, which would correspond to `typeof(int).MakeReferenceType()`.

Notice that these are two different kinds of "reference"s, completely orthogonal to each other.

(In fact, there's a third kind of "reference", `System.TypedReference`, which is just a `struct`.
There's also a fourth type of reference, the kind that every C programmer knows -- the pointer, `T*`.)

Comment: IsByRef also makes a lot more sense with a VB background, where the same method signature would be: Sub Foo(ByRef x as Integer)

Comment: Thanks to all responders!  Like I said, "an obviously misunderstanding of the purpose of .IsByRef"  ... and to think that I originally was using .IsValueType but changed to .IsByRef as I wanted to to test for 'null-ness' thinking that .IsByRef was the converse of .IsValueType (if it was, it would be .IsRefType d'oh!)

Answer (score 5):

You want to check if it is a [value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isvaluetype.aspx).

```
typeof(object).IsValueType :- false
typeof(int).IsValueType :- true
```